# Draft gets saved to O365 group instead of user's draft folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, outlook-for-mac

When sending on behalf of a Outlook365 group's delegated email, the draft id from Office-js can not be used to lookup for the draft with the signed in user's on graph api.

This will interrupt our flow for delegated email sending with Office365Groups, as there are no other way of obtaining the draft from graph api's groups resource.

Version: Outlook on Mac Version 16.46(21021202)

**Steps to replicate**

**Successful Case**

- Open OWA
- Change "From" address to office365group@yourgroup.ca
- Observe the draft, it gets put inside the user's draft folder, which could be found with signed in user since it's placed in the user's draft folder

**Failed Case**

- Open Outlook and navigate to Preferences -> Accounts -> Advanced -> Delegates -> "Open these additional mailboxes"
- Add ie: office365group@domain.com as a delegate
- Change the send from to the just added group
- Observe the draft, it gets put inside the group's office365group@domain.com draft folder, the draft is inaccessible using graph's service with the signed in user since it is placed in the group's draft folder.

Comment: Are you facing this issue in New Mac Outlook or Classic Mac Outlook UI? Can you please try your scenario on new UI and share the feedback?

Comment: This is same as this GitHub issue and more updates will be present on GitHub issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1819